# Firebase authentication with redux and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add authentication to a react website using firebase
I currently have this createasyncthunk

```
    export const signin = createAsyncThunk<
  // Return type of the payload creator
  User | void,
  // First argument to the payload creator
  userData,
  // Types for ThunkAPI
  {
    rejectValue: errorInterface;
  }
>('authentication/signin',  (user, thunkApi) => {
  const { email, password } = user;
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user;
      return user;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message, error.code)
      const errorMessage: errorInterface = { message: error.code };
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(errorMessage);
    });
});
```

the user type is imported from fire base
the userData is the following interface to represent credentials used to log in

```
interface userData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

the error interface is the following

```
interface errorInterface {
  message: string;
}
```

the authentication slice is this

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signin.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.isAuth = false;
      })
      .addCase(signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.isAuth = true;
        if (action.payload) {
          state.user = action.payload;
        }
      })
      .addCase(signin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.isAuth = false;
        if (action.payload) {
          state.message = action.payload.message;
        }
      })
  },
});
```

The problem is that signin.rejected is never trigered. Even when the catch block runs, rejectwithvalue is not updating the payload. I know the catch block is running because I can see the error in the console. Please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if that could cause this problem, but the pattern `await` with `.then` (and `.catch`) looks a bit strange. The usual pattern is `try {  await ... }  catch { ... }`

Comment: The comment above about not mixing await with promise is very true. If you use only one of them it would make the code more readable (and mistakes easier to catch). You also don't return the value from await, so I assume, that success scenario from the example doesn't work too.

Comment: Do any of you have any idea the rejected part is not working. Pending and fullfield and run and update state properly but, rejected is not being reached

Comment: Changing the function to async await and specifying the type of error (firebase error in this case) I should expect fixed the problem.